# Unable To DeleteRealm after .Dispose() Called

Tags: c#, .net-core, realm

Loading in my data

```
Uri.TryCreate(realmPath, UriKind.Relative, out var outPathUri);
RealmConfigurationBase configuration = new FullSyncConfiguration(outPathUri, _currentUser, _realmFile)
{
    ObjectClasses = typesInSelectedRealm,
    SchemaVersion = 1
};

_realmInstance = Realm.GetInstance(configuration);

if(_realmInstance != null) _realmInstance.RealmChanged += LoadDataOnChange;
```

Trying to copy .realm file with same format from a USB Drive

```
if(_realmInstance != null) 
{
    _realmInstance.RealmChanged -= LoadDataOnChange; // figure it's good to clear all external references to Realm object
    _realmInstance.Dispose();
    GC.Collect();
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // both of these are me trying to just make darn sure that everything is cleaned up and has had enough time to do so
    Realm.DeleteRealm(_realmInstance.Config); // error
}
```

Error thrown: `The process cannot access the file '...\test.realm' because it is being used by another process.`

I've already seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772154/replace-realm-file-while-app-is-running), which is the closest I've found to my issue and a possible solution, although it was for IOS so I'm not sure how much is applicable to my situation.

Comment: It's applicable. If you connect to Realm - you're connected and it won't be deletable. You have to delete it *before* any initial connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the Realm is still being used by the synchronization thread - e.g. if you added a whole lot of data to it and it hasn't been uploaded yet. What you can do is either wait for the upload to complete by calling:

```
await _realmInstance.GetSession().WaitForUploadAsync();
_realmInstance.Dispose();
// wait a second
// delete
```

or manually stopping the session (but that would it's possible that not all data has been uploaded):

```
_realmInstance.GetSession().Stop();
_realmInstance.Dispose();
```